# Iterate between date range in SQL

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have data that looks as follows:

```
start_date | end_date   | value
-----------------------------
2022-01-01   2022-01-05   10
2022-01-01   2022-01-04   5
2022-01-03   2022-01-06   100
```

I want to sum the values of rows, that are started, but not yet ended. For a single date I can write

```
SELECT SUM(value) FROM `xxx` WHERE start_date <= '2022-01-04' AND end_date > '2022-01-04');
```

to get all "open" rows on Jan 4th (110).

What's the easiest way to get these values for every day between two dates in SQL in a single query? It's a MariaDB server.

Ideally the result would look like this:

```
date       | open_values
------------------------
2022-01-01   15
2022-01-02   15
2022-01-03   115
2022-01-04   110
2022-01-05   100
2022-01-06   0
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What determines `started`, that a `start_date` is present? What is the `value` at started? What does `not yet ended` mean, is the `end_date` null in this case? Also, which `date` is used for the output column, `start_date`? I'm a little confused on the output total for 110 on the 4th, as there's only 1 record with the 4th that has 10?

Comment: @PaulT. Yes, a `start_date` is always present. The `value` of a row is set on creation and never changes. `Not yet ended` means `end_date` is later than the date queried (or, in my real data set, it is not set, but that should be trivial to add later). The output date has to be supplied by some kind of algorithm or has to include at least every `start_date` and every `end_date` to work. On the 4th the value is ´110´ because it includes the first and the last row. The second row has already "ended" on the 4th. The first and the last row have started but not yet ended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6844/sql-server-calendar-table-example/) to return the individual dates. JOIN to it and use a conditional SUM to calculate the total `value`, per day.

```
SELECT c.CalendarDate
       , SUM( IF(t.End_Date > c.CalendarDate, t.value, 0) ) AS TotalValue
FROM   CalendarTable c INNER JOIN YourTable t 
            ON t.Start_Date <= c.CalendarDate
            AND t.End_Date >= c.CalendarDate
GROUP BY c.CalendarDate 
ORDER BY c.CalendarDate
;
```

**Results:**

> ```
> CalendarDate | TotalValue
> :----------- | ---------:
> 2022-01-01   |         15
> 2022-01-02   |         15
> 2022-01-03   |        115
> 2022-01-04   |        110
> 2022-01-05   |        100
> 2022-01-06   |          0
> ```

Technically, you could also use a CTE. However, a calendar table will be more efficient.

```
-- Demo: Generate 1 year's worth of dates
WITH recursive CalendarCTE AS (
   SELECT '2022-01-01' AS CalendarDate
   UNION ALL
   SELECT DATE_ADD(CalendarDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
   FROM   CalendarCTE
   WHERE  CalendarDate < '2023-01-01'
)
-- INSERT INTO CalendarTable (CalendarDate)
SELECT c.CalendarDate
       , SUM( IF(t.End_Date > c.CalendarDate, t.value, 0) ) AS TotalValue
FROM   CalendarCTE c INNER JOIN YourTable t 
            ON t.Start_Date <= c.CalendarDate
            AND t.End_Date >= c.CalendarDate
GROUP BY c.CalendarDate 
ORDER BY c.CalendarDate
;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=dcac0ea0cc50ac1ec02495510509e9ff)*

Comment: Awesome, I got the CTE example it to work, thank you!
You need to use `CalendarCTE` in your first FROM clause. Also the second WHERE clause is unneccessary/doesn't do anything - what were you trying to do?

Comment: Also the IF clause in SUM() is unneccessary but the second JOIN condition should read ´t.End_Date > c.CalendarDate´

Comment: Ah, thanks. Fixed! As far as the WHERE clause, the original requirement was a bit fuzzy, so so I was trying different things and left it in by accident :)

Comment: `... but the second JOIN condition should read t.End_Date > c.CalendarDate` That would return a different result than you posted. Could you clarify what results you expect and why?

Comment: Specifically, do you want to exclude `2022-01-06` or no?

Comment: You are right, I kind of mixed the SUM condition and the date selection in my head. Thanks again, this works great!